# Retrieving reason for deletion in Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There's S3 used in the project but presumably some files were deleted. When I query S3 I get the following response:

```
4b3bc846-a737-4aec-84bf-734f798bca39
The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: )
```

I tried the following:

1. Studying the [Setting lifecycle configuration on a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) article. I used the Java AWS SDK  to get the lifecycle configuration:

> amazonS3Client.getBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName).getRules();

but it resulted in an `AmazonS3Exception: A request you provided implies functionality that is not implemented`

2. Getting the bucket policy with `amazonS3Client.getBucketPolicy(bucketName).getPolicyText()` but it returned `null`.
3. Manually retrieving objects in the bucket and drawing a sensible conclusion (i.e. files that are older than x weeks/month/years are gone). But I found out that the dates are scattered (from 2018 to 2022).

My question is there any way to find exactly why the file was deleted? Maybe S3 logs history of files somewhere? Is there any other reason for deletion except for manual deletion?

Comment: If [CloudTrail event logging for S3 buckets and objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-cloudtrail-logging-for-s3.html) was enabled you'd know which IAM identity deleted them.

Comment: Cloudtrail logs is the only way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable (but of course is not retroactive) [S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) to log the detailed operations executed on a bucket.

> Server access logging provides detailed records for the requests that
> are made to a bucket. Server access logs are useful for many
> applications. For example, access log information can be useful in
> security and access audits. It can also help you learn about your
> customer base and understand your Amazon S3 bill.